# Why am i getting"Error Tokenizing Data" while reading a file in python?

Tags: python, file, dataframe, tokenize

Here is the code
[image]

[image]

df = pd.read_csv("File path")

Comment: Would you please have a look - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question!

Answer (score 0):

you could also try;

```
data = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Please note that this will cause the offending lines to be skipped.

Comment: I have already tried with this alternative but failed miserably

Comment: I think there was a problem in reading the data file since the size of the data was big enough for my memory to read it, so i was suggested that i should use a laptop with a big memory size (RAM) or use an additional hard disk drive.

Comment: Thank You So Much for trying to help.    I have got a laptop with bigger Ram so that issue is resolved now.